# how to create buttons in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am making a game that has 50 buttons and everybutton has an identity as a color and an id. On clicking every button there color  changes to what it has been defined. If the user clicks on the 25th button , he wins. Only  three tries for clicking. I am however unable to do the first step of creating buttons. Please help. I use angularjs1.

```
<html ng-app="Bluebox">

 <head>
   <title>BlueBox</title>
   <script src="angular.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div ng-controller="BoxController">
      <button type="button" value = "bluebox"  >
        <li ng-repeat="x in boxlength">
            {{index+1}}
        </li>
    </button>

    </div>

    <script>
        angular.module("Bluebox",[])
            .controller("BoxController",["$scope",function($scope){

              $scope.boxlength=50;
              $scope.index=0;


           }])
    </script>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: angularjs is not python, `x in boxlength` doesn't mean `x in range(50)`, you need to have an array of some elements that you want to display. Also I think you have the wrong order: `<li>` should be wrapping your `<button>`

Comment: Here is a demo for you to play around with: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ewCyKIRgKWhXGC9bl77j?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-repeat is not at the right place. You want to repeat buttons.

```
<button ng-repeat="..." type="button" value="bluebox"></button>
```

Then the format of ng-repeat is not correct. This directive doesn't repeat a number of times, it repeats in an array.

What we usually do is create a method that create an array based on a number:

```
<button ng-repeat="i in times(number)" type="button" value="bluebox"></button>
```

Get number could look like:

```
$scope.number = 5;
$scope.times= function(x) {
    return new Array(num);   
}
```

Since the array created has indentical "values" you need to track by $index

```js
function Main($scope) {
  $scope.number = 50;
  $scope.times= function(x) {
    return new Array(x);   
  }
}

angular.module('test', []);
angular.module('test')
  .controller('Main', Main);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="Main">
    <button ng-repeat="i in times(number) track by $index" type="button">{{$index}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's better to initialise the array instead of using a function to create it dynamically. Your function `times()` will be executed multiple times (_which doesn't affect anything visually_) due to digest cycles